# SQLAlchemy use model object after insert

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I would like to use my model object after db insert because it is in a really convenient format. I tried the following:

```
@app.route("/user", methods=["POST"])
def create_user():
    with db.session_scope() as session:
        user = User(
            name=request.form["name"],
            gender=request.form.get("gender")
        )
        session.add(user)
        session.flush()

    return json.dumps(user, cls=ModelEncoder)
```

Somehow I cannot use the `user` object after the session has committed (that's basically what happens when closing the `with` block. Is there a way to do this? Right now it throws:

```
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError: Instance <User at 0x258b19a9978> is not bound to a Session; attribute refresh operation cannot proceed (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/bhk3)
```

in the lasts line of the example

Answer (score 0):

Including an session.expunge(user) after the flush did the trick. Didn't think it would work because it is before the commit, but it did

Comment: Works thanks to the flush. It pushes the changes held in the session to the DB (and I think changes the state of the instance from pending to persistent).